# String Replace | Shell/bash file

Tags: string, awk, sed, str-replace

I am trying to replace string using `sed` from sh file.

Issue: After 'connection' it has blank line and its '-url' string comes in the next line, in addition requires to replace port number and password string as well. Using sed I am not able to remove blank line after connection.

**Original String:**

```
connection

-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.11\:1551/password1 /connection-url
```

**Replace with**:

```
connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.90\:1555/password2 /connection-url
```

I tried below commands which didn't worked:

```
sed -i 's/connection[\t ]+/,/g' sed-script.sh

sed 's/\connection*-\connection*/-/g' sed-script.sh
```

Comment: This does not look like XML at all. Please [edit] the question to show the `sed` command you tried, and explain how it failed to work. If this really is XML, why are you not using an XML tool like `xmlstarlet`?

Comment: @tripleee: it is shell file, updated the command which i tried to replace the white/blank space after connection

Comment: As an aside, your `sed` might not understand `\t`. But as outlined in my answer, the problem is more fundamental than that.

Comment: Your example shows `password1` being replaced with `password2` in addition to having the whitespace between "connection" and "-url" zapped. If this is part of your question, please include a decription of this in the prose discussion, too.

Comment: The IP address also changes between the input and the output. Either fix your example or update the text to clarify the criteria for those changes.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` processes a line at a time by default; if you want to check whether an empty line follows another line, you have to write a `sed` script to implement that.

I would go with Awk or Perl instead for this particular task.

```
perl -p0777 -i -e 's/connection\n\n-url/connection-url/' file

awk '/^connection/ { c=1; next }
    c && /^$/ { c++; next }
    c && /^-url/ { $1="connection" $1; c=0 }
    c { print "connection-";
        while(--c) print "" }
    1' file >file.new
```

Perl, like `sed`, has an `-i` option to replace the file in-place.  GNU Awk has an extension to do the same (look for [`-i inplace`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html)) but it's not portable to lesser Awks.

The Perl `-0777` option causes the whole file to be slurped into memory as a single "line", line feeds (`\n`) and all.  If the file is very big, this will obviously be problematic.

The Awk script takes care to put back the lines it skipped if it turned out to be a false match after all.

Comment: Hi @triplee,

Executed above mentioned awk script but it didn't worked.

Script:

awk '/connection- */ { c=1; next } c && /^$/ { c++; next } c && /^-url/ { $1="connection-url"; c=0 } c { print "connection-"; while(--c) print "" } 1' connection-string.sh  >/tmp/file1.sh



cat /tmp/file1.sh  

Output:  <connection

Comment: My apologies, I had the wrong regex for the first `/^connection/` line.  Updated now.  The Perl script also needed a minor fix -- sorry I was not in a place where I could test this when I originally wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS="\n+{n}" '{$1=$1} 1'  Input_file
connection -url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.11\:1551/password1 /connection-url
```

Could you please try following once.

```
awk '/^connection/{val=$0;next} NF && /^-url/{print val $0;val=""}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.11\:1551/password1 /connection-url
```

Comment: The first script will lose all empty lines. The second script will lose a `connection` which isn't followed by `-url`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: please see the details for both script output.

As correctly mentioned by triplee

Script 1:  
awk -v RS="\n+{n}" '{$1=$1} 1' connection-string.sh

Output: <connection -url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.11\:1551/password1 /connection-url>

Issue: It keep space between connection & url

Script 2: 

awk '/^connection/{val=$0;next} NF && /^-url/{print val $0;val=""}' connection-string.sh

Output: 
-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.11\:1551/password1 /connection-url>

Issue: It removes connection

Comment: @user3817627, could you please use `\`` back-ticks for your comments to be wrapped up in code tags as it is NOT clear to me.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Please find the details:

Script 1: 
`awk -v RS="\n+{n}" '{$1=$1} 1' connection-string.sh` 

Output: <connection -url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.11\:1551/password1 /connection-url> 

Issue: It keep space between connection & url 

Script 2: 
`awk '/^connection/{val=$0;next} NF && /^-url/{print val $0;val=""}' connection-string.sh` 

Output: -url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.11\:1551/password1 /connection-url> 

Issue: It removes connection

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the blank line after 'connection' using `tr`.

`echo <input string> | tr -d "\n"`

Where we can see that we want the `\n` character by running the string through `od -c`:

`0000000   c   o   n   n   e   c   t   i   o   n  \n  \n   -   u   r   l
0000020   >   j   d   b   c   :   o   r   a   c   l   e   :   t   h   i
0000040   n   :   @   1   0   .   1   0   .   1   0   .   1   1   \   :
0000060   1   5   5   1   /   p   a   s   s   w   o   r   d   1       /
0000100   c   o   n   n   e   c   t   i   o   n   -   u   r   l  \n`

Comment: This will remove all newlines, including the terminating one, making the file invalid as a POSIX text file.

Comment: You can add a terminating newline with `echo "" >> file.txt` if required.

Comment: Or for a one liner, piping the output into echo appends a `\n` character: `echo <input string> | tr -d "\n"| xargs echo`

Comment: Actually the `echo` is superfluous; `xargs` with no arguments runs that by default (though this is arguably obscure).

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` -

```
sed -E '
  /connection$/,/^-url/ {
    /connection$/ { h; d; }
    /^$/            d
    /^-url/       { H; s/.*//; x; s/\n//g; }
  }
' old > new
```

Assumes no stray whitespace, and that a `connection` on a line by itself *should* be followed by a line that starts with `-url`...